# Predicate required in Core Data fetch request?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I would like to omitt the predicate in an NSFetchRequest in order to delete all managed objects for an entity.

However, when there is no predicate (according to the SQL debugger), the fetch request is not executed. According to Apple the predicate should be optional.

How would I need to change my code to remove the predicate? Any ideas? Thank you!

```
- (void)deleteEntity:(NSString*)entityName inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
    {  
        NSFetchRequest * request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TableStructure" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
        //[entities setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID
        NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = 'est'"];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *entitiesArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@: Error fetching context: %@", [self class], [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"entitiesArray: %@",entitiesArray);
        return;
    }

    for(NSManagedObject *entity in entitiesArray) {
        [context deleteObject:entity];
    }

    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [context save:&saveError];
}
```

### Update 2

It seems that I call my fetch request before the database is ready. How can I make sure that my request is not called before the core data database is ready?

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? Does it silently fail?

Comment: Stephen, the request returns an empty NSArray (count = 0). When checking the SQL codes in the debugger window, I see no SQL commands when the predicate is ommitted. However, when the predicate is included, the request runs fine.

Comment: Check did you call your managedObjectContext: method for your "context" Value like this 
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [AppDelegate managedObjectContext];

Comment: R.A. I have updated my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't assign the predicate if you don't want it. Remove following lines:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = 'est'"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: When I remove these lines, my code does not work (as described in my comment above).

Comment: I do this all the time and get my results, check in your database if you have TableStructure entities before it executes the request. And you could try: request.predicate = nil;

Comment: You still don't have any debug information on when it crashes? It's hard to see what's wrong with only info that your array has a 0 count. I would guess though that something is wrong with your NSManagedObjectContext, just check if it's created correct and doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: It seems that I call my fetch request *before* the database is ready, which I have verified by NSLog statements.

Comment: The more you screw up, the better you become in debugging :-)

Comment: Thats true, ggfela. In addition, asking question on Stackoverflow clears my mind.

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't the database be ready without the predicate, but ready with it?

Answer (score 0):

I issued my fetch request before the Core Data database was ready.

To solve this issue, I have now added the call `ImportFormulasInRequest` to the UIDocument openWithCompletion handler, which encapsulates my core data database:

```
- (void)useDocument
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.myDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
        // does not exist on disk, so create it
        [self.myDatabase saveToURL:self.myDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    } else if (self.myDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        // exists on disk, but we need to open it
        [self.myDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            [self ImportFormulasInContext:[self.myDatabase managedObjectContext]];
        }];
    } else if (self.myDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        // already open and ready to use
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        [self ImportFormulasInContext:[self.myDatabase managedObjectContext]];
    }
}
```